# List indices must be integers or slices, not str; - DIctionary error in text based game for class

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax-error

In the code, the player has a dictionary set to them with weapon details in them.

```py
    weapons = {
        "sword" : {
            "damagelow" : 3,
            "damagehigh" : 7,
            "hitrate" : 25,
        },
        "axe" : {
            "damagelow" : 6,
            "damagehigh" : 10,
            "hitrate" : 50,
        },
        }
```

This is later called in the lines

```
"randomizer = random.randrange(int(weapons["sword"]["damagelow"],["sword"]["damagehigh"]))"
```

,producing the error List indices must be integers or slices, not str. I've had no luck getting it dealt with.

I am hoping for it to read the dictionary, and then roll the dice based on the damagelow/damagehigh for combat.

Comment: You forgot `weapons` on the 2nd one. Note: since the values are already integers, there's no need for the `int` call.

Comment: @001: You were faster :-)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `weapons`:

```
randomizer = random.randrange(weapons["sword"]["damagelow"],weapons["sword"]["damagehigh"])
```

Additionally, there's no need to cast it to an integer as it already is a number.

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for the probably dumb mistake, thank you for your time and helping me with my code. Have a fine day Jan :) [thanks to 001 as well]